# w3facility seems all together dodgy, but does attribute

Tags: discussion

It contains some of my SE questions/answers.

http://w3facility.org

The site appears to attribute technically correctly as per the SE policy, but I'm not sure that it's ok.

What do we think?

Comment: Ok, sorry, it was a duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be linking to user pages (as required by attribution rules).